# File wx/wx.h does not exist

Tags: c++, wxwidgets, vcpkg

I've been trying for a while now to compile and use wxwidgets for a c++ project, but every time I think I get close, the same error occurs. `File wx/wx.h does not exist`. I've tried building wxwidgets with cygwin and VS2019, just downloading the binaries, and finally(what I've most recently tried), downloading the library using the [vcpkg](https://vcpkg.io/en/) package manager. I made an environment variable to the include folder within wxwidgets(C:\vcpkg\packages\wxwidgets_x86-windows\include), and I included `wx.h` by typing

```
#ifndef WX_PRECOMP
    #include "wx\wx.h"
#endif
```

For clarification, I'm on windows 10 and I'm using clang++. Any help would be greatly appreciated, since I've had this problem for a while now and I couldn't find any answers.

Comment: You need to define the include search path to where `"wx\wx.h"` can be found.  Add the option `/I "path\to\wx"`.

Comment: Thank you, It didn't error immediately now, but now clang errors saying `clang++: error: linker command failed with exit code 1120 (use -v to see invocation)`. Yes, I did also insert `-L path/to/wx` as a parameter too.

Comment: @sharpcdf, are you using clang even with MSVC? If not - how did you build wxWidgets with it?

Comment: Sorry if I'm not being specific in my original post, but I've downloaded-not built-the library using vcpkg(`vcpkg install wxwidgets`), and I have all wx files, my problem is compiling a wxwidgets app, not building the library.

Comment: @sharpcdf, in your OP you said you tried building it with `Cygwin` and `MSVC`. Also, I doubt that there is a precompiled binaries produced with `CLANG` - you should build the library yourself.

Comment: Pre-compiled binaries are produced by MSVC and MinGW only - no CLANG ones. Unless you absolutely sure that there is ABI compatibility - you should build it yourself if you want to use CLANG.

Comment: Once again, I downloaded the library with vcpkg. You can look at the wxwidgets package [here](https://vcpkg.io/en/packages.html)(search up `wxwidgets`). I did NOT download binaries for clang++, cygwin or MSVC, and I did NOT build the library __at all__. I downloaded it with vcpkg. And please answer my original question. I'm asking why clang errors with `linker command failed` and `wx/wx.h not found`, not how to build and implement wxwidgets.

Comment: Unless you're trying to say that you can only use a specific compiler if downloading with vcpkg(in which case please be more specific), please answer my question.

Comment: @sharpcdf, can you post the command generated that is trying to link your proogram? And the full path to the downloaded libraries?

Comment: @sharpcdf, like I said in your OP you said: `I've tried building wxwidgets with cygwin and VS2019,`, so I was under the impression that you problem was with those 2 compiler setup. Sorry if it was misleading.

Comment: I compile my c++ file by typing
`clang++ main.cpp -o main.exe -L C:\vcpkg\packages\wxwidgets_x86-windows\include -I C:\vcpkg\packages\wxwidgets_x86-windows\include`

the error is `clang++: error: linker command failed with exit code 1120 (use -v to see invocation)`

The folders of wxwidgets can be seen [here](https://prnt.sc/18u469n) (if its helpful)
and sorry for not being specific in my OP

Comment: @sharpcdf, can you add `-v` as suggested by the error? Also, I believe you command is incomplete - you should use something like `clang++ main.cpp -o main.exe -IC:\vcpkg\packages\wxwidgets_x86-windows\include -IC:\vcpkg\packages\wxwidgets_x86-windows\lib -LC:\vcpkg\packages\wxwidgets_x86-windows\lib`. I am also not sure how clang chooses which libraries to link - you might add the `-l` option (lower case `L`) with the list of libraries to link.

Comment: Alright, I'll try it.

Comment: Include folder contains all classes definitions. In the lib folder there should be a setup.h file that has to be included - however I'm not sure of the exact placement of it - check the lib folder and fix the path as appropriate for the second `-I` option. That file contains all configuration specific definitions for the build so it needs to be included.

Comment: I tried compiling it with your suggestion, to no avail. I also tried it with `-v`, but nothing different happened.

Comment: @sharpcdf, please post your updated command. And did you find the setup.h in the lib folder?

Comment: @sharpcdf, also one `stupid` question - did you get the library version built with your version of clang++?

Comment: All I know is that vcpkg installed the latest version of wxwidgets, and my updated command is the same as yours, because `setup.h` is located within `lib\mswu\wx`.

Comment: @sharpcdf, OK, try this `clang++  -v main.cpp -o main.exe -IC:\vcpkg\packages\wxwidgets_x86-windows\include -IC:\vcpkg\packages\wxwidgets_x86-windows\lib\mswu\wx -LC:\vcpkg\packages\wxwidgets_x86-windows\lib`. Also, you should try supplying the libraries to that command, i.e. try adding `-lwxbase-3.1.4 -lwxcore-3.1.4`. Please check the lib folder for the proper library names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build or get and use wxWidgets in [many different ways](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.1.5/overview_install.html), all of which work, but you can't mix different ways together and expect them to work.

If you want to use vcpkg, you should follow the [instructions here](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.1.5/plat_msw_install.html#msw_install_and_build) and you can read [this post](https://www.wxwidgets.org/blog/2019/01/wxwidgets-and-vcpkg/) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Building with MSVC is very straightforward.

1. Open MSVC environment.
2. Navigate to the wxWidgets\build\msw and open wx_vcN.sln (for 2019 version N should be 16).
3. Select "Build -> Batch Build...", Click "Select ALL", then "Build".
4. Go drink a cup of coffee. ;-)
5. Open the file wxWidgets\samples\minimal\minima_vcN.sln (use maximum N available, let MSVC convert the solution if needed).
6. Select "Build -> Build Solution".
7. Open the Windows Explorer, navigate to the folder wxWidgets\samples\minimal, find the `miinimal.exe` binary and double click on it.

In order to build your own code:

You can either copy the folder of the miinimal sample somewhere, open it back up from new location and adjust `Include` and `Library` paths as appropriate (old way) or use the properties file supplied with the newest release of wxWidgets (create an empty Win32 project and then copy this file as appropriate) - there is an instruction on either MS web site or in the wxWidgets documentation.

If you have any problems with any of the steps - let us know.

Thank you.

Comment: Thank you, but I already have the library downloaded with vcpkg, the problem I'm having is compiling a wxwidgets application with clang++. It hasn't errored as much when I sent `-I path/to/wx` as a parameter, but clang++ errors about the linker command failing.